# Creatin a dynamic array including car's year and make but unable to save my first output

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, structure

I'm working on a specific problem where the output is:
How many cars do you wish to catalog: input
car# 1:
Please enter the make: input_make1
Please enter the year made: input_year1

car# 2:
Please enter the make: input_make2
Please enter the year made: input_year2

Here is your collection:
input_year1 input_make1
input_year2 input_make2

My code is 90% complete, but In my " here is your collection output",I'm not able to save the first one.please help.

```
   #include<iostream>
   using namespace std;
   struct car
   {
    char make[60];
    int year;
   };
   int main(void)
    {
    cout<<"How many cars do you wish to catalog: ";
int j;
cin>>j;
cin.get();
car *ps=new car;
int i;
for(i=1;i<=j;i++)
{
for (i=1;i<=j;i++)
{
cout<<"car# "<<i<<": "<<endl;
cout<<"Please enter the make: ";
cin.get(ps->make,60);
//cout<<"\n";
cout<<"Please enter the year it was made";
cin>>ps->year;
cin.get();
}
cout<<"Here is your collection: \n";
cout<<ps->year<<" "<<ps->make;
}

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a few issues with your code. From what I can tell, you're trying to get a number of cars from the user (j), store them, then print them out. The issue is is that you only have one storage variable (ps). Every time the second loop iterates, it overwrites the ps variable. To fix this you want to create an array of size j. I recommend using a vector, as you don't know the size of the when you compile:

```
std::vector cars;
//Gets the input from the user
for(int i = 0; i < j; ++i){
    car temp;
    temp.make = inputStuff;
    temp.year = moreInputStuff;
    cars.push_back(temp);
}
//Prints the array out
for(int i = 0; i < cars.size(); ++i){
    cout << cars[i].make << " " << cars[i].year;
}
```

The other issue is your double loop. Because they use the same variable to iterator (i), once the inner loop exits, the outer loop will exit as well.

Comment: Yes,I think only the input_year2 input_make2 is available on the output the first output on the here is your collection has been overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

If by "save the first one" you mean the first element of the array then I'll point out arrays in C++ start at index 0. So adjust your loop accordingly: `for (i = 0; i < j; ++i )`

However you have bigger problems with this such as incorrectly using dynamic allocation and leaking memory, etc. If you want to allocate an array of cars (aka more than one) then do this: `car* ps = new car[j];`

You then need to explicitly delete them so as not to leak memory with the array delete operator after you're done using them: `delete [] ps;`

If you want to loop through this dynamically allocated array of cars and update a member of a specific car struct element use the array operator again: `cin >> ps[i].year;`

Answer (score 1):

You can't save your entry because you only have one car object and one pointer so you just change the values of that object. You need to create an array of car objects .

Answer (score 1):

You can store your car structures in a vector as you make and fill them.
make sure you `#include <vector>`

```
vector<car *> stored_cars;

for ( int i = 0; i < num_cars; ++i ) {
    car * ps = new car;
    // populate ps with data
    stored_cars.push_back(ps);
}

for ( vector<car *>::iterator it = stored_cars.begin(); is != stored_cars.end(); ++it ) {
    // you can dereference it to get at the car pointer
    (*it)->blah

    // make sure you delete the dynamically allocated structs when you are done with them
    delete (*it);
}
```

A better approach would be not to use dynamically allocated memory for the cars.
You'd have a vector of car, `vector<car>`, and you would just push_back the cars from the stack, and wouldn't have to worry about deleting them all when you are done (vector's destructor will take care of that)

Comment: vectors still use dynamically allocated memory ... it just manages it for you ;-)